# mvc autocomplete jquery json list not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am doing a MVC 5, Entity Framework, APP.

I have an autocomplete for Cities but the response of `autocomplete` do not appear in the list.

Maybe I am missing a jquery.js.

Here is my HTML code...
[image]

My Controller looks like this.

```html
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetCityByCountryState_Id(int country_id=1, int state_id=2, string prefix="")
        {
            IEnumerable<Cities> cityName = _cityRepository.GetByCountryState_Id(country_id, state_id, prefix);
            return Json(cityName.Select(m => new
            {
                id = m.city_id ,
                name = m.Description
            }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

I Put an alert `OnSuccess` and it returns the ID and Value.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

[image]

Here is the list of .js I have included in

```
_Layout.cshtml
```

when I run tha page in Chrome, It shows the following error `OnSucess`

[image]

It shows an error in Jquery.js.

Any idea?

Comment: did you check your action is working, I mean returning some result ?

Comment: yes, I added an alert(value) onsucess, and it shows the result.

Comment: then your code seem correct , however for reference see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/creating-autocomplete-textbox-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

Comment: Also check is there any error on console ?

Comment: I updated the Post. It shows an error in Jquery do not what it means... thanks

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is a Jquery error `uncaught typeerror this.options.messages.results is not a function`.
It is solved modifing the `messages:` tag.